# Is it possible to bind a Spring Form to an Object using the constructor or by mapping multiple fields to a single value via a custom Editor?

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, properties

I have an Object who's internal representation is not conducive to data entry.  I have a class with multiple custom components, one of which is a Range class.  The Range class is easiest to input using two text field inputs rather than as one text field that uses a custom PropertyEditor.

I have a fully functional constructor that could handle the multiple field option but I don't believe there's anyway to get Spring to use the constructor rather than setter injection.  Am I wrong about that?  If I'm not, is it possible to bind two form elements to a single object member using a custom PropertyEditor or some related method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the problem, assuming your Range object has 'rangeStart' and 'rangeEnd' properties.
With one of the fields use `<spring:bind path="yourObject.rangeStart">` and with the second field use `<spring:bind path="yourObject.rangeEnd">`.

Comment: Sorry.  I wasn't at all clear.  The problem (as seen in the edits above) is that the Range class is nested inside of the class the form is actually bound to.  I hear that in Grails I could say `<spring:bind path="food.range.start">` but I couldn't figure out if that's possible  in Spring.

Comment: You can, IFF range is non-null.  A NPE will be thrown otherwise, the binder will not construct the range instance for you if it is null.